# How to fix text inside a block that grows

Tags: html, css

This is the problem: the block itself increases upwards, and the text inside it is with it, but I need the text to always remain in one place. Help me please
How to fix text inside a block that grows
It seems there is no error positioning, but it still does not work

```css
.section01 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 223px;
  height: 181px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.section01:hover {
  animation: width-up 5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes width-up {
  from {
    width: 223px;
    height: 181px
  }
  to {
    width: 223px;
    height: 340px
  }
}

.numb {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.17px;
  line-height: 25.31px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.numbdescr {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 25.31px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section01">
  <div class="numb">
    01
  </div>
  <!-- /.numb -->
  <div class="numbdescr">
    Юридические услуги
  </div>
  <!-- /.numbdescr -->
</div>
<!-- /.section -->
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/4kmy9b3q/1/

Answer (score 2):

Animate `padding-top` instead of the `height`:

```css
.section01 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 223px;
  height: 181px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.section01:hover {
  animation: padding-up 5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes padding-up {
  from {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding-top: 159px;
  }
}

.numb {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.17px;
  line-height: 25.31px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.numbdescr {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 25.31px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section01">
  <div class="numb">
    01
  </div>
  <!-- /.numb -->
  <div class="numbdescr">
    Юридические услуги
  </div>
  <!-- /.numbdescr -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is quite hard to identify since you didn't add the HTML code. I'll try to give some advice anyway. Maybe you could do something like this:

```
<div class="section-container">
        <div class="section-box-that-will-grow-on-hover"></div>
        <div class="section-box-that-contains-your-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde iste reiciendis facilis voluptatem ad, odit quia quaerat quis voluptatibus aperiam enim rerum quidem dignissimos, voluptas explicabo, ab fugiat consectetur. Ipsum?</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .section-container{
            color: #fff;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 200px;
        }

        .section-box-that-will-grow-on-hover{
            background: #000;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            z-index: -1;
            transition: transform 1s ease;
            transform-origin: bottom;
        }

        .section-container:hover .section-box-that-will-grow-on-hover{
            transform: scale(1, 1.2);
        }

        .section-box-that-contains-your-text{
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
```

If you have problems with the concept of Positioning in CSS, go and watch some tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kejG8G0dr5U&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4L731ispRfGAabXeRpM4RL6).